# Why is this JavaScript function called twice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

In this sample from W3 School Array Sort, the function displayCars seems to be called 2 times. It's called before the first function and inside the first function. Could someone explain the reasoning behind this? I'm having trouble understanding why. Thanks in advance.

```js
var cars = [
{type:"Volvo", year:2016},
{type:"Saab", year:2001},
{type:"BMW", year:2010}]

displayCars();

function myFunction() {
    cars.sort(function(a, b){return a.year - b.year});
    displayCars();
}

function displayCars() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  cars[0].type + " " + cars[0].year + "<br>" +
  cars[1].type + " " + cars[1].year + "<br>" +
  cars[2].type + " " + cars[2].year;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: It only runs once.

Comment: Works fine for me... "Volvo 2016<br>Saab 2001<br>BMW 2010"

Comment: They probably want to display the list unsorted when the page loads, and then when someone wants to sort, they sort and display the list again.

Comment: it only runs once! I can see why it might for you though... Something somewhere else is calling myFunction? That may be why

Comment: I guess you call `myFunction()` somewhere else in the code.

Comment: It is called only once. `function myFunction()` calls it when it runs but the code as is now doesn't call `myFunction()`. It is probably invoked when a button is pressed but you didn't post that code.

Comment: I feel like we are all misinterpreting this... Maybe not why it is called more why is there a function myFunction in the first place? Then it isnt a very good question since we dont know lol

Comment: @L_Church Perhaps. But, since the title of the question asks why it runs twice, that's what we are answering.

Comment: "Why is this JavaScript function called twice?" I don't think so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is not called twice in your snippet. I'm assuming there's more code we haven't seen, which calls `myFunction`; the purpose of calling the function twice would then be to show the effect of the sorting function. Assuming `myFunction` is called after the display function, the program would do the following:

- Display the cars in the (unsorted) order they start in
- Run `myFunction` which sorts the cars then displays them again

This would allow the user to see the difference between the car list before and after it's sorted.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks so much for all of your explanations and info. I tested it by removing the first displayCars() and it still works, but it does not show them before the sort, only after the sort. So it is basically called twice to show before and after from what I can gather.  Here is a link to the "Try it" page: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_sort_object1

Answer (score 6):

It's actually only being called once because the second call for `displayCars()` is inside of `myFunction`, which is never being called.

Change the code to call `myFunction` and stay away from W3 Schools as it is well known to have incorrect and outdated information. Use the [Mozilla Developer Network instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

```js
var cars = [
{type:"Volvo", year:2016},
{type:"Saab", year:2001},
{type:"BMW", year:2010}]

myFunction();

function myFunction() {
    cars.sort(function(a, b){return a.year - b.year});
    displayCars();
}

function displayCars() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  cars[0].type + " " + cars[0].year + "<br>" +
  cars[1].type + " " + cars[1].year + "<br>" +
  cars[2].type + " " + cars[2].year;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: I personally think this is the best answer. He's not trying to get why it's run twice he's asking why it's called twice. You've clearly shown how it's meant to run: Get the cars then run the function to sort the list then display them! I'll add you a +1 for your downvote lol

Comment: @L_Church It's not called twice. It's written into the code twice, but only called/run once.

Comment: It's understanded it doesn't reach it but it's intended to be called!

Comment: @L_Church As I've stated before. The intent may have been something else, but I'm answering the question that was asked.

Comment: we are thinking different i agree with you... your change is correct and he was asking why it was written twice stop confusing me and take the upvote lol

Comment: @ScottMarcus It got a downvote because it's clear that this is an example problem so the intended code is to show the cars, sort, and show them again. tbh I'd remove it but I can't now.... :/

Comment: @Feathercrown I don't think it was that clear at all. Especially, since it's coming from W3 Schools.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Well, whether it was clear or not, I apparently did interpret it correctly. However, I do realize now that your answer *is* useful.

Answer (score 2):

I is caalled twice to show the result before sorting and after sorting.

You need to add the call of `myFunction` as well.

```js
function myFunction() {
    cars.sort(function(a, b){return a.year - b.year});
    displayCars();
}

function displayCars() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=
  cars[0].type + " " + cars[0].year + "<br>" +
  cars[1].type + " " + cars[1].year + "<br>" +
  cars[2].type + " " + cars[2].year + '<hr>';
}

var cars = [{ type: "Volvo", year: 2016 }, { type: "Saab", year: 2001 }, { type: "BMW", year: 2010 }];

displayCars(); // show content

myFunction();  // sort and show content
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Well, **your** code calls it twice, but he OP's code does not.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, then the question does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is called once, but why is it mentioned twice in the code is for you to see the results as they are and after they've been sorted.

Answer (score 0):

It is run only once. You are not call myFunction() function. If you call it the array will sort.
Try this one.

```
var cars = [
{type:"Volvo", year:2016},
{type:"Saab", year:2001},
{type:"BMW", year:2010}]

myFunction();

function myFunction() {
    cars.sort(function(a, b){return a.year - b.year});
    displayCars();
}

function displayCars() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  cars[0].type + " " + cars[0].year + "<br>" +
  cars[1].type + " " + cars[1].year + "<br>" +
  cars[2].type + " " + cars[2].year;
}
```

myFunction() will sort array. 
displayCars() will show array.